# Can snippets take parameters in lift?

Tags: scala, lift

Is there a way in lift to pass parameters to snippets?

I am trying to write a *pluraize* filter for my page that will display the word "user" or "users" depending on how many there are:

```
1 user
2 users
```

The way it works in Django is called [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#pluralize) and they are written as follows:

```
You have {{ num_messages }} message{{ num_messages|pluralize }}.
```

So here you can see *pluralize* function takes an integer *num_messages* and outputs and appropriate string - either empty "" or "s".

EDIT: Note that the **num_messages** in this case is an actual context variable, passed down to the template from the view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass parameters to snippets, yes.

```
class MySnippet {
  def foo: NodeSeq = {
    x = S.attr("myparam") openOr "myparam: Y U NO DEFINED!?"
    <p>I got {x}!</p>
  }
}
```

Use:

```
<lift:MySnippet.foo myparam="3"/>
```

Or, newer Lift 2.3+ style:

```
<div class="lift:MySnippet.foo?myparam=3"/>
```

Comment: Except one should never use open_!.  Instead: val x = S.attr("myparam") openOr "Dude, myparam is not defined"

Comment: Hm... but could I actually pass a context value, like num_messages (above) to the snippet?

Comment: Also - is there way to get by without these "Boxes"? I am not sure how it is better than option - just more confusing.

Comment: Also what does "<p>I got {x}!</p>" mean? How can you just insert html code into scala code like that? I tried - it works, but its weird!

Comment: @drozzy `Box` *is* similar to `Option`, but has some nice additional functionality, like being able to carry a failure/exception as well as being `Full(x)` or `Empty`.  I'm not an expert, but here's some reading to look over: http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2010/04/16/understanding-lifts-boxt-monad/.  I don't think you can avoid `Box` in Lift, and once you start using it a bit you'll start to appreciate it.

Comment: @drozzy "<p>I got {x}!</p>" is an XML literal which is a feature of the Scala language (not Lift-specific).

Comment: @overthink let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/978/discussion-between-drozzy-and-overthink)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="main" class="cl1 cl2 lift:surround?with=default;at=content">
```

This is also a snippet invocation with parameters.

See lift docs: [Lift docs, 3.4.1 Snippets in markup](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.4.html)

> In order to indicate that content is dynamic, the markup contains a snippet invocation. That typically takes the form class="someclass someothercss lift:mysnippet". If a class attribute contains lift:xxx, the xxx will be resolved to a snippet. The snippet may take attributes. Attributes are encoded like URL parameters... offset by a ? (question mark), then name=value, separted by ? (question mark), ; (semicolon) or & (ampersand). name and value are URL encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do it like this way.

```
<div class="lift:MyClass">
  You have <span class="num_messages"/>.
</div>
```

and your lift code would look something like:

```
class MyClass {
 def render = "num_messages" #> (num_messages + pluralize("message", num_messages))
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! I wander if I could inject it into multiple ids at the same time. But that's another question...