# Django tags and filters in Lift?

Tags: django, scala, lift

This is a generalization of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511665/can-snippets-take-parameters-in-lift) about pluralize filter:

Does lift have an equivalent of Django's tags and filters?

**Tags** are small piece of predefined code that can be used directly in html template, for example:

```
{% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

renders the time right now in the given format.

**Filters**

Filters operate (in html template) on the context variables in the template, for example:

```
{{ value|capfirst }}
```

if called on a value "john" will result in "John". Or:

```
{{ value|length }}
```

will render the length of the string into the template.

As you can see the filters operate on the context variables that are passed to the template.

Comment: By design, no code is allowed on html templates in Lift.

Comment: Please read http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-3.html#toc-Chapter-3 Also, if you have questions about Lift, please ask them on the Lift mailing list or at least take a look at the questions asked previously on the Lift mailing list

Comment: I read that * book 10 times already! I don't think i'll get anything more out of it. The question about tags was simply for completeness - as I am really interested in filters.

Comment: Also - for the person who down-voted me please let me know what the problem with my question is so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering tags, you could define those yourself with snippets.

As snippet is basically a callback much as a Django tag is. You don’t get any easier syntax, though, because Lift’s templates are pure XML/Html.

```
<Lift:Tag.now format="jS F Y H:i" />
```

And the logic would be defined in

```
class Tag {
  def now: NodeSeq = // ...
}
```

---

Filtering is something you generally can’t do in a Lift template because Lift doesn’t allow any variables in a template. The whole concept is thus inapplicable. (You *could* do XML transforms or or bind magic but that would be a bit too much for a simple `value.length`.)

No, if you need the length of some value in your Html, you will have to define that inside the snippet and expose it.

If you really can’t live without filters in your template (though I can assure you, it is a good thing to separate all HTML template and code and it works once you are used to it), have a look at [Scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/) which may be used together with Lift as well.

Comment: Wow, cool, I didn't know Scalate was part of scala, and already integrated into Lift!

Comment: You will have to plug it yourself and I’m not sure how good it is documented, but in general it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that filtering is something that I can't do in Lift. It is nice to see someone actually answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic should be in the `render` method of a snippet. Display code in pure Scala (rather than in a template language hybrid) is a first-class citizen with respect to testing, IDE's and refactoring tools.

These kinds of transforms don't come built-in, but you can add them with implicits:

```
class HappyString(s: String) {
  def capfirst = ....
}

implicit def toHappyString(s: String) = new HappyString(s)
```

Then call these in your `render` method before binding whatever value it is you're generating.